# <ul> <li> should only show on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi all I was hoping to get some help with adding a link in a nav menu when you scroll further than the header [my site](http://danceforovariancancer.com.au) has a header above the navbar and I need the home button to only display on scroll, purely for links, and I'd like to apply an ease in style or jquery ease effect to it. So it comes in from the left to where it is situated now, the whole navbar content needs to be centered before and after this happens so all the other buttons would need the smooth transitioning too.

```
<div class="container-fluid DFOCpadding">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class=" text-center ">
        <span class="toptext">DANCE FOR OVARIAN CANCER</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar">
<div class="container">             
    <div class="navbar" id="navbar">
        <div class="wrapcenter">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="http://danceforovariancancer.com.au">HOME</a></li>             
            <li><a class="scroll" href="#register"><span class="register">REGISTER</span></a></li>
            <li><a class="scroll" href="#faq">FAQ's</a></li>    
            <li><a class="scroll" href="#acts">ACTS</a></li>    
            <li><a class="scroll" href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>  
            <li><a class="scroll" href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>      
        </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I can only ask a question every 90 minutes and am very tired so going to bed and hopefully can wake up to some answers, so here is another question.. I'm making a child site for [this site](https://ovariancancer.net.au/) and as you can see their navbar sticks to the top but the header above the navbar doesn't. I've looked for answers on this but they use javascript very relative to the OP's code so I can't get it to work for my solution. Does anyone know and easy alternative so it sticks when it scrolls past the dance for ovarian cancer header and then unsticks when you go back to the top?

Cheers, Nik

I added a margintop class with

```
.margintop {
margin-top: 100px;
```

}

but it doesn't work cause ..well for reasons I always realise after the fact but that an experienced programmer would probably forsee. Any how that's how I'm leaving the site so any answers would be great :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to set display:none to #navbar div then use this jquery script to show it on scroll.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){

          $('#navbar').show();

    });
});
```

Comment: how do you use a jquery script? do I just chuck the code from above into a .js file and src it or is it something from the actual huge jquery.js file?

Comment: You shold import jquery js then import my script